# AAPT: error: unexpected element <applications> found in <manifest> - Andoid Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

I'm trying to finish my final year project by building a mobile app. Every time i run the code on a simulator it pops me up with this error. Specifically on the "debug\AndoidManifest.xml" file. Could someone help me?

```
<applications
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Login" >
    <activity android:name="com.example.login.Login" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.login.Register" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.login.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</applications>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag should be `<application>` not `<applications>`.
remove `s` from it.

Comment: Thank you!
I already tried this and saved it, but after i run it it again, it's like automatically rewrite the final "s". Why?

Comment: you should change the manifest file you can edit, I mean don't change the autogenerated manifest file under debug directory

Comment: Yes you were right. I fixed it. I was trying to modify the "debug\AndroidManifet" file. Despite that, i had to modify the main\AndoidManifest" file. Thanks

Comment: Of course! I am  trying to upvote you, but I cannot find it :) Could you please tell me where I can find the upvote activity?